# How can I fine-tune the position of FabButton in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How do I adjust the Right and Bottom margin of this fab button which is constructed via Jetpack Compose?

This is the Scaffold layout that declares the extended Fab button.

```
Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBar(
                content = { ... },
                backgroundColor = PrimaryVariantLight,
            )
        }, backgroundColor = PrimaryLight,
        floatingActionButton = {
            ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
                text = { FAB() },
                onClick = { },
                backgroundColor = SecondaryLight,
                elevation = FloatingActionButtonDefaults.elevation(8.dp)
            )
        },
        floatingActionButtonPosition = FabPosition.End
    ) { paddingValues ->
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .fillMaxHeight()
                .padding(8.dp),
            contentPadding = paddingValues,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {
            items(myItems) { myItem ->
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think this padding is defined within the `Scaffold` implementation, and you probably should not be modifying it, as you will violate the design guidelines if you do.

If you want to increase the padding, you can simply use the [`padding`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).padding(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp)) Modifier on the `ExtendedFloatingActionButton`. This however **does not support negative values**.

> Negative padding is not permitted — it will cause `IllegalArgumentException`

If you want to decrease the padding, you can try the [`offset`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).offset(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp)) Modifier to change the position of the `ExtendedFloatingActionButton`:

```
ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
    modifier = Modifier.offset(x = 4.dp, y = 4.dp)
    text = { FAB() },
    onClick = { },
    backgroundColor = SecondaryLight,
    elevation = FloatingActionButtonDefaults.elevation(8.dp)
)
```

This will move the FAB `4dp` into the text direction of the current locale, and `4dp` to the bottom.

Answer (score -1):

To adjust the right and bottom margin of the extended FabButton in Jetpack Compose, you can use the modifier parameter of the ExtendedFloatingActionButton to apply a Modifier that specifies the desired margins. You can use the padding modifier to achieve this.

```
ExtendedFloatingActionButton(
            text = { FAB() },
            onClick = { /* FabButton onClick listener */ },
            backgroundColor = SecondaryLight,
            elevation = FloatingActionButtonDefaults.elevation(8.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(end = 16.dp, bottom = 16.dp) // Adjust the right and bottom margins here
        )
```

you can adjust the end (right) and bottom margins as per your requirement. The padding modifier adds space around the FabButton, effectively adjusting its position within the Scaffold layout.

Comment: this moves it further away by "x" dp from top and bottom

Comment: use negative values for end (right) and bottom margins to move the FabButton further away from the right and bottom edges of the screen.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy

Comment: @Akshay The `padding` Modifier does not allow negative values according to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/layout/package-summary#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).padding(androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp));